How can i interpret dropped frames possibly associated with a lone "task" in Chome dev tools
I have a requestAnimationFrame loop which renders some webGL. It seems that it does this very fast, but i still see these dropped frames in the profile. It doesnt always seem to align, with this "Task" that i have selected but i wonder if it is related.
Why are these requestAnimationFrames spaced out in this way if they take such a short time to execute?
Within these 4 visible frames, i should see 4 of these stacks not 3?
What is preventing the red frame to the right from having a requestAnimationFrame execute?

